# UK Business Visa Query

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens, application-status

I'm a freelance journalist based in Pakistan. I'm a working student. Having won a journalism award recently, I had to apply for a UK visa to receive the award. My airfare and accommodation are being provided by the event organizers and they provided reasonable evidence for my hotel and flight reservation.

Since I'm a freelancer, the letters I received from the publications state me as a freelancer contributor, without mentioning the pay because there is no fixed amount. Given my estimated monthly earning, I quoted that in the salary box. My bank statements match my claims.

However, I'm worried if I will make a strong case. Since my trip is being sponsored by a registered company, does my pay and bank statement still matter? And does it have to be healthy?

Comment: I'm note sure "receiving an award" qualifies as business, and thus whether a business visa is appropriate.

Comment: It's an official presentation ceremony. What could have been the appropriate category then?

Comment: The award also include a cash prize, by the way.

Comment: Does the cash prize require you to do something (make a speech, run some kind of workshop, present for photos, promote the event) to get it? Did you look at "permitted paid engagement" visa?

Comment: And yes, your pay and bank statement still matter. They would be used to evaluate the possibility that you would return back to Pakistan, and will not stay in UK or work illegally.

Comment: No, I don't need to run any workshops or promote the event. However, I will have to give a speech and while at the event, will be photographed. It might be presented by Christiane Amanpour. Yes, I did check Permitted Paid Work but its eligibility requirements included if I wanted to come to the UK to do specific paid work without having to be sponsored under the points-based visa system.

Comment: @GeorgeY actually my bank statement is weak, considering I'm a student (my university letter attached), which is why I'm worried. Also, some friends told me that if my visa category wasn't correct, they wouldn't have taken my passport.

Comment: Since you already submitted your application, then it doesn't seem like you can do anything right now. No need to worry until you hear back from them.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can't do anything now. Just trying to reassure myself. Haha

Comment: Good luck, and please come back and let us know once you get your visa!

Comment: This is post-submission anxiety. Your activities all fall withing those listed in Appendix V. You should always submit a history of bank statements regardless of your sponsorship.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, @GayotFow. Really hoping to get the visa!

Comment: Also, @GayotFow having seen you pretty active here, I wanted to inquire if my weak bank statement will have any effect on my application, considering my visit is fully sponsored by a well-respected UK organization and I'm a working student, meaning I can't have a hefty amount in my bank?

Comment: Look at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: @GayotFow I checked with the UKVI about my visa application status (submitted last Monday) and they say it is yet to be assessed by an ECO. Is that usual?

Comment: @UmerAli not unusual, sounds fine.

Comment: @GayotFow I might have to shift from my current pllace. Should I notify the UKV?